# Apply CSS to multiple pages

Tags: html, css

How can I apply a .css file on many pages at the same time ? 
I have hundreds .html files in many different directories and I need to apply the same style sheet in this pages, but I can't manually change every file to link it with my style sheet.
How can I do it ?

Comment: Write a script to do that or use a build tool that does it for you.

Comment: if you have already a css included everywhere you could `@import` another css from there

Answer (score 2):

The simplest options is to write a script that loops over every HTML file in your directory and adds the `<link />` entry in every page.

Otherwise, if there is a CSS file that is already linked by **every** page, you can append your CSS file to it, or use an [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/@import) directive.

Answer (score 0):

Reorganize your directory structure so that every html file is on the same level. As long as they are in the same level, you could provide your link using the same tag using `..` which means the directory above.

### For example:

---

html

- dir1
- dir2

css

- style.css

(html files inside dir1, dir2, etc.)

---

Here you could just put 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: Ok but than means I need to write the link to the css file in every html file ? I can't do that because I have too many files so I can modify them one by one.